# Charpit's Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the complete integral of partial differential equation
$$\displaystyle z^2 = pqxy $$

I have solved this equation till auxiliary equation:
$$\displaystyle \frac{dp}{-pqy+2pz}=\frac{dq}{-pqx+2qz}=\frac{dz}{2pqxy}=\frac{dx}{qxy}=\frac{dy}{pxy} $$

But I have unable to find value of p and q.
**EDIT:**

```
p = ∂z/∂x
q = ∂z/∂y
r = ∂²z/∂x²  = ∂p/∂x
s = ∂²z/∂x∂y = ∂p/∂y or ∂q/∂x
t = ∂²z/∂y²  = ∂q/∂y
```

Comment: Can you make clear what the question is?  I see an equation with five variables, not a differential equation at all.  What is a function of what, and where are the differentials?  From the third line, maybe z, p, and q are all functions of x and y, but unless some are specified there is not enough information for a solution.

Comment: So is the equation $z^2=xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ where z is a function of two variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the equation is 
$$z^2=xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
 I would be tempted to see the symmetry in $x$ and $y$ and try solutions of the form $z=(xy)^n$.  What happens then?

Comment: What happens is that $n=\pm1$. And then?

Comment: So you have a solution $z-xy=0, F_x=p=y, F_y=q=x$  But F_p seems to be $0$ for Charpit's method.

Comment: Right. I asked because I thought we were after *every* solution of this pde, but rereading the question I am not so sure anymore...

Comment: More generally, you can have $z=c^2(xy)^c$ or $z=-c^2(\frac xy)^c$ for $c$ positive or negative.

Answer (score 2):

let the given equation be 
$$f(z,p,q)=0  \text{ i.e, } z^2-pqxy=0$$
perform derivation w.r.t p,q,x,y,z
then write charpits relation 
$$\frac {dx}{-fp} =\frac {dy}{-fq} =\frac {dz}{(-p*fp-q*fq)} =\frac {dp}{(fx+x*fz)} =\frac {dq}{(fy+y*fz)}$$

where $fp,fq,fx,fy,fz$ are derivatives of $z^2-pqxy$ I think u got it :)
after substitutions
equate 1 and three equations i.e 
$$ \frac {dx}{qxy}=\frac {dz}{2pqxy}$$
now u can find the value of 
$$p=\frac {z+c}{2x} $$
put p in 
$$z^2-pqxy=0$$
 u can find 
$$q=\frac  {2z^2}{((z+c)y)}$$
put the p,q in 
$$dz=pdx+qdy$$
 and integrate u can get the solution :) if im wrong please correct me thanking u

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution.
perform 
$$\frac {p dp - q dq}{{pq(qy-px)}} = - \frac {ydx-xdy}{{xy(px-qy)}} $$

resulting to 
$$\frac {d(pq)}{pq}=\frac {d(xy)}{xy}$$
Integrating we get 
$$\log pq = \log xy+ \log c  \implies \frac {pq}{xy}=c \implies p= \frac {cxy}q. $$

Substitute this value in your prob. and proceed as usual.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 1):

using multipliers p,q,x & y in 1st, 2nd, 4th & 5th equations and equating it with equation 3rd.

$$\implies  \frac {dz}{2pqxy}=(pdx+qdy+xdp+ydq)/pqxy+pqxy-pqxy+2pxz-pqxy+2qyz$$

from question $z^2=pqxy$:

$$\implies dz/(2z^2)= (pdx+qdy+xdp+ydq)/2pzx+2qxy$$
$$ \implies dz/2(z^2)={d(px)+d(qy)}/2z(px+qy) $$
$$\implies \frac {dz}z=\frac {d(px+qy)}{px+qy}$$
$$\implies \ln(z)=\ln(px+qy)+\ln(a)$$
$$ \implies z=a(px+qy).$$

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1):

from your auxiliary equations: use
$$\frac{zp\ dx + xz\ dp}{xyzpq - xyzpq +2pxz^2} = \frac{q\ dy + y\ dq}{pqxy - pqxy + 2yzq}. $$
$$\implies \frac{p\ dx + x\ dp}{2pxz} = \frac{d(yq)}{2yzq} \implies \frac{d(xp)}{xp} = \frac{d(yq)}{yq}$$. on integrating we get 
$xp = yqa$ ($a$=constant). then you complete using  $dz=p\ dx+q\ dy$  (using the given equation $z^2 = pqxy$)

Answer (score 0):

A much easier solution can be obtained by introducing new dependent/independent variables U=log u, X=log x, Y=log y. Then, with P,Q denoting the first partial derivatives of U with respect to X,Y, respectively, the PDE becomes

PQ=1,

which can be solved very easily by Charpit's method.